# Can a LibGDX be created as a command line app?

Tags: java, command-line, cmd, libgdx

Is it possible to create a LibGDX application that only uses the command line, and doesn't have a window/display? Something I could throw on a server without needing to set up X or something?

Comment: Why exactly would you want such a thing, considering graphics display is the whole point of libgdx?

Comment: I want access to LibGDX's Math and File classes for my server.

Comment: Are you making a game server, or a server that's unrelated to gaming?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. LibGDX has a headless backend. See https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/tree/master/backends/gdx-backend-headless. There are no tutorials unfortunately.

Answer (score -1):

To put it simply, no.

LibGDX is a framework for deploying **graphical**  games on multiple platforms. What you are describing is a **text based game**. Essentially, you would make a better text based game without LibGDX, so let's take that out of the question.

A text based game can be done in java with the `java.util.Scanner` Class, and the default `java.lang` library. To make a text based game, you simply process input as raw text (Rather than controls), and return the outcome in raw text (Rather than graphics).

To sum this up, LibGDX is the wrong direction to go in if you want to make a console game.